# Seamlessly Refresh iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, cognos

We have about a dozen Cognos reports that we would like to cycle through 4 portlets on a dashboard.  I was playing around with iframe's, but swapping out content from another domain (the cognos report url's are on a different domain) is proving a little challenging.  Any ideas on how to preload the next report, and when loaded, transition to the portlet to the new report, all using javascript?  Any thoughts or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hidden iframes to preload the next report. When the hidden iframes onload event fires, swap the current iframe with the hidden one. jQuery `.replaceWith()` would come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden iframes to preload the next reports. In your case, you would have 4 shown iframes and 4 hidden iframes.

- When your 4 shown iframes are being displayed, you could assign `src`
  of the next 4 reports to the 4 hidden iframes.
- When you want to
  display the next 4 reports, just toggle the states of all iframes
  (`$.toggle`) and again assign the next 4 reports to the 4 hidden iframes